# Angular ng build --prod outputhashing, My own names

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, build, command-line-interface

When we use the `ng build --prod` command and have outputhashing set to "all", we get output files with a hash, e.g. main.dse2324dacx3423.js. However, how to add your own text after main.myOwnText.js

During the `ng build --prod` command, I want it to get versions from my package.json
`{ "name": "app-name", "version": "24.02.01", "scripts": { "ng": "ng", "start": "ng serve", "build": "ng build", "test": "ng test", "lint": "ng lint", "e2e": "ng e2e" },`

So how can I make the files generate the way I want?

I want the application to generate files with the name of my version that it downloads from package.json
main.24.02.01.js etc..

Comment: This is bad idea. Hashing should have any meaning.

Comment: That's why I want to add the versioning of my application to the files so that it matters. If I generate a new version of the application, the version will change.
So why is this a bad idea?

Comment: The hash is generated from the content, if the code changes, the hash changes. Leave it to bundler to name your files.

Comment: Ok I see. But is it possible to have any influence on the naming of these files in general? Even the impact on the hash

Comment: Not without messing with the webpack config, which is also not recommended.